# How to retrieve Kerberos token using Keytab in Python 2.6

Tags: python, windows, kerberos, keytab

I am creating a Python script which will be run as a batch script in domain joined Windows 2012/2016 server. Script should have the capability to create Kerberos token from a keytab. Keytab is created to store credentials of a Active directory service account.

There are few Python modules which can create Kerberos token, like winkerberos, requests_kerebros which can be used in Windows environment. But none of them allows to use keytab.

Have anyone was able to use Keytab with any Python module in Windows?

Thanks

Comment: If a kerberos ticket be obtained via a call from python to the underlying os, then have a look at the `subprocess` module.  This works in Linux - a kerberos ticket can be obtained from within python via a call to the os from `subprocess`, I would expect similar behavior in Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was looking into it. Do you have any working example?